# Using Mathematica to solve a nonlinear system of parameters

Tags: nonlinear

I'm looking for some sets of solutions for this nonlinear system. I only have to respect the conditions, getting numerical values to use for another thing:

$\delta_1>10 |\lambda_1| (1)$

$\delta_2>10 |\lambda_2| (2)$

$\Delta_1>10 |\Omega_1| (3)$

$\Delta_2>10 |\Omega_2| (4)$

$\Delta_3>10 |\Omega_3| (5)$

$\frac{|\lambda_1|^2}{\delta_1} = \frac{|\lambda_2|^2}{\delta_2} (6)$

$\Delta_1 + \frac{|\Omega_1|^2}{\Delta_1} +\frac{|\Omega_3|^2}{\Delta_3} = \delta_1 + \frac{|\Omega_2|^2}{\Delta_2}  (7)$

$\delta_2 + \frac{|\Omega_1|^2}{\Delta_1} +\frac{|\Omega_3|^2}{\Delta_3} = \Delta_2 + \frac{|\Omega_2|^2}{\Delta_2}(8)$

$\alpha = \frac{\lambda_1 \Omega_1}{\delta_1} - \frac{\lambda_2 \Omega_2}{\delta2} (9)$

$\beta = \frac{\lambda_1 \Omega_1}{\Delta_1} - \frac{\lambda_1 \Omega_1}{\Delta_2} (11)$

$\alpha < 0.1$  $(11)$

$\beta < 0.1$  $(12)$

$|\lambda_1|=1.0$  $ (13)$

Naturally, $\delta_1, \delta_2, \Delta_1, \Delta_2$ and $  \Delta_3$  $\epsilon$  $\Re $.

I'm using Mathematica to solve this nonlinear system of parameters (image below) by using NSolve, where I give some parameters and apply the conditions, but it's not working.

[image]

I know it is far away from a good strategy to attack this problem. Could someone help me with a code in Mathematica that **works setting a few parameters and the computer calculates the others (respecting all the conditions)?**

Comment: Please do not post images of your work. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, people who wan to helo you will have do a lot of work to reproduce your problem so they can experiment with possible solutions.